# Cherokee Build on OBS

Tags: linux, rpm, opensuse, rpmbuild, cherokee

I am trying to create a rpm package of Cherokee from source via the Open Build Service for OpenSuse.
I have uploaded the SUNWCHerokee.spec but the build failed and I cannot figure out why.
Here is the log file. I hope somebody can help me.

```
[    0s] Using BUILD_ROOT=/var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/.mount
[    0s] Using BUILD_ARCH=i586:i486:i386
[    0s] Doing kvm build in /var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/root
[    0s] 
[    0s] 
[    0s] cloud114 started "build SUNWcherokee.spec" at Thu Oct  9 08:06:28 UTC 2014.
[    0s] 
[    0s] Building Cherokee for project 'home:LycheeLinux' repository 'openSUSE_13.1' arch 'i586' srcmd5 '2e81a43464d00d5536b7e59a41c9c8b3'
[    0s] 
[    0s] processing recipe /var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/.build-srcdir/SUNWcherokee.spec ...
[    0s] running changelog2spec --target rpm --file /var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/.build-srcdir/SUNWcherokee.spec
[    1s] init_buildsystem --configdir /var/run/obs/worker/2/build/configs --cachedir /var/cache/build --prepare --clean --rpmlist /var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/.build.rpmlist /var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/.build-srcdir/SUNWcherokee.spec build rpmlint-Factory ...
[    3s] [1/29] preinstalling filesystem...
[    3s] [2/29] preinstalling glibc...
[    3s] [3/29] preinstalling fillup...
[    3s] [4/29] preinstalling libattr1...
[    3s] [5/29] preinstalling libbz2-1...
[    4s] [6/29] preinstalling libcap2...
[    4s] [7/29] preinstalling libelf1...
[    4s] [8/29] preinstalling libgcc_s1...
[    4s] [9/29] preinstalling liblua5_1...
[    4s] [10/29] preinstalling liblzma5...
[    4s] [11/29] preinstalling libpcre1...
[    4s] [12/29] preinstalling libpopt0...
[    4s] [13/29] preinstalling libz1...
[    4s] [14/29] preinstalling attr...
[    4s] [15/29] preinstalling libacl1...
[    4s] [16/29] preinstalling libncurses5...
[    5s] [17/29] preinstalling libselinux1...
[    5s] [18/29] preinstalling libreadline6...
[    5s] [19/29] preinstalling bash...
[    5s] [20/29] preinstalling diffutils...
[    5s] [21/29] preinstalling m4...
[    5s] [22/29] preinstalling sed...
[    5s] [23/29] preinstalling tar...
[    5s] [24/29] preinstalling grep...
[    5s] [25/29] preinstalling coreutils...
[    6s] [26/29] preinstalling permissions...
[    6s] [27/29] preinstalling aaa_base...
[    6s] [28/29] preinstalling rpm...
[    7s] [29/29] preinstalling pam...
[    7s] 
[    7s] [1/8] preinstalling libdb-4_8...
[    7s] [2/8] preinstalling libsepol1...
[    7s] [3/8] preinstalling libuuid1...
[    7s] [4/8] preinstalling net-tools...
[    7s] [5/8] preinstalling perl-base...
[    7s] [6/8] preinstalling libblkid1...
[    7s] [7/8] preinstalling libmount1...
[    8s] [8/8] preinstalling util-linux...
[    8s] copying packages...
[   11s] reordering...cycle: libcrack2 -> cracklib
[   11s]   breaking dependency libcrack2 -> cracklib
[   11s] done
[   15s] ### WATCHDOG MARKER START ###
[   15s] booting kvm...
[   15s] linux64 /usr/bin/qemu-kvm -no-reboot -nographic -vga none -net none -cpu host -kernel /boot/vmlinuz -initrd /boot/initrd -append root=/dev/disk/by-id/virtio-0 panic=1 quiet no-kvmclock nmi_watchdog=0 rw rd.driver.pre=binfmt_misc elevator=noop console=ttyS0 init=/.build/build -m 3000 -drive file=/var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/root,if=none,id=disk,serial=0,cache=unsafe -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=disk -drive file=/var/cache/obs/worker/root_2/swap,if=none,id=swap,serial=1,cache=unsafe -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=swap -smp 4
[   22s] FATAL: Module kqemu not found.
[   22s] FATAL: Module ext2 not found.
[   22s] FATAL: Module ext3 not found.
[   25s] Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/virtio-0 to appear:  ok
[   25s] fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
[   25s] [/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/vda 
[   25s] /dev/vda: clean, 3016/1281120 files, 148116/5120000 blocks
[   25s] fsck succeeded. Mounting root device read-write.
[   25s] Mounting root /dev/disk/by-id/virtio-0
[   25s] mount -o rw,defaults -t ext4 /dev/disk/by-id/virtio-0 /root
[   26s] replacing /etc/mtab with symlink to /proc/self/mounts
[   27s] ### WATCHDOG MARKER END ###
[   27s] 2nd stage started in virtual machine
[   27s] machine type: x86_64
[   27s] switching personality to 8...
[   27s] 2nd stage started in virtual machine
[   27s] machine type: i686
[   28s] mkswap: /dev/disk/by-id/virtio-1: warning: wiping old swap signature.
[   28s] Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 2047996 KiB
[   28s] no label, UUID=25dc89d1-9056-41d0-87b2-e22f5320d5d4
[   28s] swapon /dev/disk/by-id/virtio-1
[   28s] swapon: /dev/vdb: found swap signature: version 1, page-size 4, same byte order
[   28s] swapon: /dev/vdb: pagesize=4096, swapsize=2097152000, devsize=2097152000
[   28s] WARNING: udev not running, creating extra device nodes
[   28s] mount: none is already mounted or /proc busy
[   28s] mount: none is already mounted or /dev/pts busy
[   28s] logging output to //.build.log...
[   28s] processing recipe /.build-srcdir/SUNWcherokee.spec ...
[   29s] init_buildsystem --configdir /.build/configs --cachedir /var/cache/build /.build-srcdir/SUNWcherokee.spec build rpmlint-Factory ...
[   30s] running aaa_base preinstall script
[   31s] running aaa_base postinstall script
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/language...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/backup...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/boot...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/clock...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/proxy...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/cron...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/news...
[   31s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/shutdown...
[   31s] Updating etc/passwd...unchanged
[   31s] Updating etc/group...unchanged
[   31s] Updating etc/shadow...new
[   32s] initializing rpm db...
[   33s] [1/95] cumulate file-magic-5.14-4.1.2
[   33s] [2/95] cumulate filesystem-13.1-3.1.2
[   33s] [3/95] cumulate terminfo-base-5.9-33.1.2
[   33s] [4/95] cumulate glibc-2.18-4.4.1
[   33s] [5/95] cumulate fillup-1.42-269.1.2
[   33s] [6/95] cumulate libatomic1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   33s] [7/95] cumulate libattr1-2.4.47-2.1.2
[   33s] [8/95] cumulate libaudit1-2.2.3-4.1.2
[   33s] [9/95] cumulate libbz2-1-1.0.6-26.1.21
[   33s] [10/95] cumulate libcap2-2.22-10.1.24
[   33s] [11/95] cumulate libelf1-0.155-6.1.20
[   33s] [12/95] cumulate libgcc_s1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   33s] [13/95] cumulate libgdbm4-1.10-7.1.2
[   33s] [14/95] cumulate libgmp10-5.1.2-2.1.2
[   33s] [15/95] cumulate libgomp1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   33s] [16/95] cumulate libgssglue1-0.4-2.1.2
[   33s] [17/95] cumulate liblua5_1-5.1.5-5.2.1
[   33s] [18/95] cumulate liblzma5-5.0.5-2.1.20
[   33s] [19/95] cumulate libpcre1-8.33-2.1.2
[   33s] [20/95] cumulate libpopt0-1.16-24.1.1
[   33s] [21/95] cumulate libsepol1-2.1.9-5.1.23
[   33s] [22/95] cumulate libustr-1_0-1-1.0.4-29.1.2
[   33s] [23/95] cumulate libuuid1-2.23.2-3.1
[   34s] [24/95] cumulate libz1-1.2.8-3.1.2
[   34s] [25/95] cumulate net-tools-1.60-763.1.2
[   34s] [26/95] cumulate patch-2.7.1-4.1.2
[   34s] [27/95] cumulate perl-base-5.18.1-2.1.11
[   34s] [28/95] cumulate update-alternatives-1.16.10-3.1.2
[   34s] [29/95] cumulate brp-extract-appdata-2012.02.13-16.3.1
[   34s] [30/95] cumulate build-mkbaselibs-20131015-1.1
[   34s] [31/95] cumulate insserv-compat-0.1-8.1.2
[   34s] [32/95] cumulate attr-2.4.47-2.1.2
[   34s] [33/95] cumulate libacl1-2.2.52-2.1.2
[   34s] [34/95] cumulate libblkid1-2.23.2-3.1
[   34s] [35/95] cumulate libisl10-0.12-2.1.2
[   34s] [36/95] cumulate libitm1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   34s] [37/95] cumulate libmpfr4-3.1.2-3.1.2
[   34s] [38/95] cumulate libselinux1-2.1.13-4.1.21
[   34s] [39/95] cumulate libstdc++6-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   34s] [40/95] cumulate libtirpc1-0.2.3-1.1
[   34s] [41/95] cumulate libmagic1-5.14-4.1.2
[   34s] [42/95] cumulate libzio1-1.00-8.1.2
[   34s] [43/95] cumulate file-5.14-4.1.2
[   34s] [44/95] cumulate libasan0-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   34s] [45/95] cumulate libcloog-isl4-0.18.0-5.1.2
[   34s] [46/95] cumulate libdb-4_8-4.8.30-25.2.1
[   34s] [47/95] cumulate libmount1-2.23.2-3.1
[   34s] [48/95] cumulate libmpc3-1.0-5.1.2
[   35s] [49/95] cumulate libncurses5-5.9-33.1.2
[   35s] [50/95] cumulate libsemanage1-2.1.10-3.1.20
[   35s] [51/95] cumulate libreadline6-6.2-68.1.5
[   35s] [52/95] cumulate perl-5.18.1-2.1.11
[   35s] [53/95] cumulate cpp48-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   35s] [54/95] cumulate brp-check-suse-1.0-59.1.2
[   35s] [55/95] cumulate bash-4.2-68.1.5
[   35s] [56/95] cumulate build-compare-2012.01.26-20.1.4
[   35s] [57/95] cumulate systemd-rpm-macros-2-6.1
[   35s] [58/95] cumulate cpp-4.8-2.1.2
[   35s] [59/95] cumulate bzip2-1.0.6-26.1.21
[   35s] [60/95] cumulate xz-5.0.5-2.1.20
[   35s] [61/95] cumulate info-4.13a-36.1.2
[   35s] [62/95] cumulate cpio-2.11-25.1.2
[   35s] [63/95] cumulate diffutils-3.3-3.1.2
[   35s] [64/95] cumulate m4-1.4.16-14.1.2
[   35s] [65/95] cumulate make-3.82-160.2.1
[   35s] [66/95] cumulate sed-4.2.2-2.1.2
[   35s] [67/95] cumulate tar-1.26-19.1.2
[   35s] [68/95] cumulate which-2.20-2.1.2
[   35s] [69/95] cumulate findutils-4.5.12-1.1
[   35s] [70/95] cumulate gawk-4.1.0-2.1.14
[   35s] [71/95] cumulate gettext-runtime-mini-0.18.3.1-1.1
[   35s] [72/95] cumulate grep-2.14-5.1.2
[   35s] [73/95] cumulate gzip-1.6-4.2.2
[   35s] [74/95] cumulate binutils-2.23.2-8.1.2
[   35s] [75/95] cumulate coreutils-8.21-7.1.3
[   36s] [76/95] cumulate linux-glibc-devel-3.11-2.1.15
[   36s] [77/95] cumulate glibc-locale-2.18-4.4.1
[   36s] [78/95] cumulate gettext-tools-mini-0.18.3.1-1.1
[   36s] [79/95] cumulate permissions-2013.08.22.1339-2.1.2
[   36s] [80/95] cumulate rpm-4.11.1-6.2.1
[   36s] [81/95] cumulate glibc-devel-2.18-4.4.1
[   36s] [82/95] cumulate libutempter0-1.1.6-3.1.2
[   36s] [83/95] cumulate rpmlint-mini-1.5-2.2.5
[   36s] [84/95] cumulate rpmlint-Factory-1.0-84.1.1
[   36s] [85/95] cumulate gcc48-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1
[   36s] [86/95] cumulate gcc-4.8-2.1.2
[   36s] [87/95] cumulate libcrack2-2.9.0-2.1.2
[   36s] [88/95] cumulate cracklib-2.9.0-2.1.2
[   36s] [89/95] cumulate pam-1.1.8-3.1
[   36s] [90/95] cumulate pam-modules-12.1-20.1.2
[   36s] [91/95] cumulate util-linux-2.23.2-3.1
[   36s] [92/95] cumulate aaa_base-13.1-16.17.1
[   36s] [93/95] cumulate rpm-build-4.11.1-6.2.1
[   36s] [94/95] cumulate aaa_base-malloccheck-13.1-16.17.1
[   36s] [95/95] cumulate post-build-checks-1.0-119.1.2
[   36s] now installing cumulated packages
[   38s] Preparing...                          ########################################
[   39s] Updating / installing...
[   39s] filesystem-13.1-3.1.2                 ########################################
[   40s] glibc-2.18-4.4.1                      ########################################
[   40s] libz1-1.2.8-3.1.2                     ########################################
[   40s] perl-base-5.18.1-2.1.11               ########################################
[   40s] libgmp10-5.1.2-2.1.2                  ########################################
[   40s] libbz2-1-1.0.6-26.1.21                ########################################
[   40s] libgcc_s1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1        ########################################
[   40s] libstdc++6-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1       ########################################
[   40s] fillup-1.42-269.1.2                   ########################################
[   40s] libisl10-0.12-2.1.2                   ########################################
[   41s] libmpfr4-3.1.2-3.1.2                  ########################################
[   41s] libattr1-2.4.47-2.1.2                 ########################################
[   41s] libcap2-2.22-10.1.24                  ########################################
[   41s] liblzma5-5.0.5-2.1.20                 ########################################
[   41s] update-alternatives-1.16.10-3.1.2     ########################################
[   41s] libacl1-2.2.52-2.1.2                  ########################################
[   41s] libmpc3-1.0-5.1.2                     ########################################
[   41s] libcloog-isl4-0.18.0-5.1.2            ########################################
[   41s] cpp48-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1            ########################################
[   42s] libdb-4_8-4.8.30-25.2.1               ########################################
[   42s] libaudit1-2.2.3-4.1.2                 ########################################
[   42s] libgomp1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1         ########################################
[   42s] libpcre1-8.33-2.1.2                   ########################################
[   42s] libselinux1-2.1.13-4.1.21             ########################################
[   42s] libpopt0-1.16-24.1.1                  ########################################
[   42s] libuuid1-2.23.2-3.1                   ########################################
[   42s] libblkid1-2.23.2-3.1                  ########################################
[   42s] libmount1-2.23.2-3.1                  ########################################
[   42s] libzio1-1.00-8.1.2                    ########################################
[   42s] libasan0-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1         ########################################
[   42s] libitm1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1          ########################################
[   42s] insserv-compat-0.1-8.1.2              ########################################
[   42s] libatomic1-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1       ########################################
[   42s] libelf1-0.155-6.1.20                  ########################################
[   42s] libgdbm4-1.10-7.1.2                   ########################################
[   44s] perl-5.18.1-2.1.11                    ########################################
[   44s] libgssglue1-0.4-2.1.2                 ########################################
[   44s] libtirpc1-0.2.3-1.1                   ########################################
[   44s] liblua5_1-5.1.5-5.2.1                 ########################################
[   44s] libsepol1-2.1.9-5.1.23                ########################################
[   44s] libustr-1_0-1-1.0.4-29.1.2            ########################################
[   44s] libsemanage1-2.1.10-3.1.20            ########################################
[   44s] net-tools-1.60-763.1.2                ########################################
[   44s] patch-2.7.1-4.1.2                     ########################################
[   44s] terminfo-base-5.9-33.1.2              ########################################
[   44s] libncurses5-5.9-33.1.2                ########################################
[   44s] libreadline6-6.2-68.1.5               ########################################
[   45s] bash-4.2-68.1.5                       ########################################
[   45s] info-4.13a-36.1.2                     ########################################
[   45s] coreutils-8.21-7.1.3                  ########################################
[   45s] diffutils-3.3-3.1.2                   ########################################
[   45s] grep-2.14-5.1.2                       ########################################
[   45s] permissions-2013.08.22.1339-2.1.2     ########################################
[   45s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/security...
[   45s] Checking permissions and ownerships - using the permissions files
[   45s]    /etc/permissions
[   45s]    /etc/permissions.easy
[   45s]    /etc/permissions.local
[   45s] setting /usr/bin/eject to root:audio 4755. (wrong owner/group root:root permissions 4750)
[   45s] setting /sbin/unix_chkpwd to root:shadow 4755. (wrong owner/group root:root)
[   45s] setting /usr/bin/wall to root:tty 2755. (wrong owner/group root:root permissions 0755)
[   45s] setting /usr/bin/write to root:tty 2755. (wrong owner/group root:root permissions 0755)
[   45s] sed-4.2.2-2.1.2                       ########################################
[   45s] cpio-2.11-25.1.2                      ########################################
[   45s] findutils-4.5.12-1.1                  ########################################
[   46s] gawk-4.1.0-2.1.14                     ########################################
[   46s] update-alternatives: using /bin/gawk to provide /bin/awk (awk) in auto mode
[   47s] binutils-2.23.2-8.1.2                 ########################################
[   47s] update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ld.bfd to provide /usr/bin/ld (ld) in auto mode
[   47s] libutempter0-1.1.6-3.1.2              ########################################
[   48s] linux-glibc-devel-3.11-2.1.15         ########################################
[   48s] glibc-devel-2.18-4.4.1                ########################################
[   49s] gcc48-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1            ########################################
[   52s] glibc-locale-2.18-4.4.1               ########################################
[   52s] make-3.82-160.2.1                     ########################################
[   52s] tar-1.26-19.1.2                       ########################################
[   52s] which-2.20-2.1.2                      ########################################
[   53s] gettext-runtime-mini-0.18.3.1-1.1     ########################################
[   53s] gettext-tools-mini-0.18.3.1-1.1       ########################################
[   53s] gzip-1.6-4.2.2                        ########################################
[   53s] systemd-rpm-macros-2-6.1              ########################################
[   53s] cpp-4.8-2.1.2                         ########################################
[   53s] gcc-4.8-2.1.2                         ########################################
[   53s] bzip2-1.0.6-26.1.21                   ########################################
[   53s] xz-5.0.5-2.1.20                       ########################################
[   53s] libcrack2-2.9.0-2.1.2                 ########################################
[   53s] cracklib-2.9.0-2.1.2                  ########################################
[   53s] pam-1.1.8-3.1                         ########################################
[   54s] util-linux-2.23.2-3.1                 ########################################
[   54s] setting /usr/bin/wall to root:tty 2755. (wrong permissions 0755)
[   54s] setting /usr/bin/write to root:tty 2755. (wrong permissions 0755)
[   54s] setting /usr/bin/eject to root:audio 4755. (wrong permissions 4750)
[   55s] aaa_base-13.1-16.17.1                 ########################################
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/language...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/backup...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/boot...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/clock...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/proxy...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/cron...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/news...
[   55s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/shutdown...
[   55s] Updating etc/passwd...unchanged
[   55s] Updating etc/group...unchanged
[   55s] Updating etc/shadow...unchanged
[   55s] aaa_base-malloccheck-13.1-16.17.1     ########################################
[   56s] file-magic-5.14-4.1.2                 ########################################
[   56s] libmagic1-5.14-4.1.2                  ########################################
[   57s] rpm-4.11.1-6.2.1                      ########################################
[   57s] Updating /etc/sysconfig/services...
[   57s] rpmlint-mini-1.5-2.2.5                ########################################
[   57s] file-5.14-4.1.2                       ########################################
[   57s] rpm-build-4.11.1-6.2.1                ########################################
[   57s] rpmlint-Factory-1.0-84.1.1            ########################################
[   57s] post-build-checks-1.0-119.1.2         ########################################
[   57s] pam-modules-12.1-20.1.2               ########################################
[   58s] m4-1.4.16-14.1.2                      ########################################
[   58s] build-compare-2012.01.26-20.1.4       ########################################
[   58s] brp-check-suse-1.0-59.1.2             ########################################
[   58s] attr-2.4.47-2.1.2                     ########################################
[   58s] brp-extract-appdata-2012.02.13-16.3.1 ########################################
[   58s] build-mkbaselibs-20131015-1.1         ########################################
[   58s] removing nis flags from //etc/nsswitch.conf...
[   58s] now finalizing build dir...
[   59s] SIOCSIFADDR: File exists
[   60s] -----------------------------------------------------------------
[   60s] ----- building SUNWcherokee.spec (user abuild)
[   60s] -----------------------------------------------------------------
[   60s] -----------------------------------------------------------------
[   60s] + exec rpmbuild -ba --define '_srcdefattr (-,root,root)' --nosignature --define 'disturl obs://build.opensuse.org/home:LycheeLinux/openSUSE_13.1/2e81a43464d00d5536b7e59a41c9c8b3-Cherokee' /home/abuild/rpmbuild/SOURCES/SUNWcherokee.spec
[   60s] error: Unable to open Solaris.inc: No such file or directory
[   60s] ### WATCHDOG MARKER START ###
[   63s] [   43.748296] SysRq : Power Off
[   64s] [   43.814272] reboot: Power down
[   73s] ### WATCHDOG MARKER END ###
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an additional file called "Solaris.inc" that
the SUNWcherokee.spec is trying to read.